# asp.net webapi routing; string parameter getting mapped

Tags: asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I want to have a url like

```
/foo/bar/1.2.3
```

map to an action

```
public void Get(string barValue, string version)
```

in a controller called FooController.

I have the following route defined

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "FooRoute",
    routeTemplate: "foo/{barValue}/{version}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Foo", action = "Get" }
);
```

which works for `foo/bar/121` or `/foo/bar/qwerty` but not for `/foo/bar/1.2/`

How can i fix it to map to anything that comes in for second parameter to string ?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue when using the selfhost WebAPI server. This may only be an issue in the webhosted case.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net file handler could be intercepting requests that have a dot, for example, /foo/bar/1.2/. You could disable this behaviour by adding

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

to your web.config.